# What do we do with questions that ask for resources (tutorials, documentation)?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

With the public release of Magento 2, questions like this come up more often again:
[Suggest me Magento2 Theme development best tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107331/suggest-me-magento2-theme-development-best-tutorial)

- asking for external resources
- answers are likely to be "link only"
- answers still tend to be useful for a larger audience

On StackOverflow these would immediately be closed as **off topic** because:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

We don't have this close reason here, so I'd like to gather some opinions about what to do with these questions. Some options:

- close as off topic
- convert to community wiki
- leave them as they are
- move links from answers to a related tag wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have this for two or three other questions, where we created a very good, wide and detailed answer, and then closed new questions about this as duplicated

Answer (score 4):

Fabian,in my mind there are two options

- Convert to Community wiki
- leave them as they are

If we make it close as off topic that becomes confusion for users as it already  magento related and basic question for a developer.As MSE is great platform for Magento resource,so any one of developer can give answer in links or  multiple answer.Also i have seen some answers of [Ben Lessani - Sonassi](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/361/ben-lessani-sonassi) in long format and those are very use full

Also my point of view **leave them as they are**,may be in future any user can be  interest to answer this question in brief and long.

So we can use  **leave them as they are**

Answer (score 2):

I would not encourage to support theme or tutorial requests.

1. **Theme requests**
   Answers to these requests probably only contain links to other resources containing the themes. These links will break in the future making the answer worthless.
   Also these kind of questions will come in thousands of variants without them being actual duplicates: "*Where can I find a Magento2 red / blue / purple / dark / light / flat / newspaper style theme?*" and so on...
   Referring to a big community wiki Q&A about it would have my preference.
2. **Tutorial requests**
   Why does one need a tutorial? Probably there is an underlying problem. So the actual question is not for the tutorial, but how to do something: "*Where can I find a tutorial for X?*" comes from the OP's original problem "*How can I do X?*". So the actual question should be just that.
   Also again, answers to these requests probably only contain links to other resources containing the actual examples and explanation. These links could break in the future making the answer worthless.
   On SE link only answers are not encouraged.